# yup date validation on express js

Tags: express, date, validation, yup

I can't seem to get past this error `body.end_date must be a 'date' type, but the final value was: '\"2023-08-30T02:13:41.600Z\"'.` I am using express js.

this is how my code looks like

```
router.post(
  "/",
  validateHandler(
    yup.object({
      body: yup
        .object({
          name: yup.string().required(),
          price: yup.number().required(),
          start_date: yup
            .date()
            .required()
            .nullable()
            .typeError("Invalid Date on start_date"),
          end_date: yup
            .date()
            .required()
            .nullable()
            .typeError("Invalid Date on end_date"),
        })
        .noUnknown(true),
    }),
  ),
  route,
)
```

this is how pass the parameters using `POST` method

```
{
    "name": "2 DAY TRIP",
    "price": 3000,
    "start_date": "2023-08-21T02:13:41.600Z",
    "end_date": "2023-08-30T02:13:41.600Z"
}
```

I tried using other formats on date but still got the same result.